# JavaScript - Incorrect automatic rounding decimal numbers

Tags: javascript

I have big numbers coming from the backend service in my JS application. I don't want to lose any of the digits after the decimal place.

However, when a number like 999999999999999.99 is assigned to a variable in JS, it rounds it to 1000000000000000 and 99999999999999.99 turns to 99999999999999.98.

Both numbers are within the limits. i.e. less than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

See the above in action in the screenshot below:

[image]

Can anybody shed some light on it, please?

Comment: Try `parseFloat` on the number

Comment: Related (on code-review, though): https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158781/rounding-javascript-decimals

Answer (score 1):

`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` only guarantees precision for integers below it, not decimals.

In fact there are no decimals in Javascript only floating point numbers. When you try to represent a number with too much precision it'll just be rounded to the nearest 64 bit floating point number.

If you actually want decimals you will need to use a decimal library like [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/) or you could write your own.